# p90 heap usage is 60%, what will happen if I double the message consumption?

Tags: java, heap-memory, performance-estimation

I have a system, which consumes x messages per second, which leads to a p50 (50th percentile) heap usage of 25%, and p90 (90th percentile) heap usage of 60%.

Now, we aim to double the consumption rate of messages to 2x per second. I want to understand the impact of this on heap usage, given the percentile heap usage.

Basically, I am worried about two types of messages around the 90th percentile, which are consumed together. Since in both the cases, we're taking 60% of heap, can this cause a memory limit exceeded exception?

Any pointers appreciated.

---

Approach one : Gradual increase in consumption rate, along with monitoring.

- Issue : We are not getting the 2x messages right now. We would be getting those later, so we won't know whether the system is working fine with the 2x consumption rate.

Answer (score 1):

**Stable p90:**

If your memory allocation system is efficient and can adapt to increased workloads, the p90 heap usage might remain around 60%. This could occur if the system allocates memory gradually in response to demand or if automatic garbage collection handles memory release effectively.

**Increased p90, but still manageable:**

Doubling message consumption might increase the p90 heap usage, possibly even by 50-100%. However, as long as the heap size is sufficient and doesn't reach its full capacity, the system might still function adequately.

**Heap exhaustion and service disruption:**

If the system cannot handle the increased memory demand from doubled message consumption, the p90 could rise significantly, approaching or exceeding the available heap size. This can lead to heap exhaustion, causing service disruptions, crashes, or performance degradation.